# Search for XML feeds usind Iphone

Tags: iphone, search, rss

hi can anyone give me hint of how to start coding for an app to search the internet and find the rss xml url's using a string provided by the user.

thanks upfront.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use XML parsing to implement this.I suggest use touchXML

-(void)callwebservice{

```
NSString *path = @"YOUR URL";
[self grabRSSFeed:path];
```

}

## pragma mark -

## pragma mark  Touch XML

## pragma mark -

-(void) grabRSSFeed:(NSString *)blogAddress {

```
// Initialize the blogEntries MutableArray that we declared in the header
blogEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    

// Convert the supplied URL string into a usable URL object
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: blogAddress];

// Create a new rssParser object based on the TouchXML "CXMLDocument" class, this is the
// object that actually grabs and processes the RSS data
CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

// Create a new Array object to be used with the looping of the results from the rssParser
NSArray *resultNodes = NULL;

// Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed
resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//Node you want to parse" error:nil];

// Loop through the resultNodes to access each items actual data
for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {
    
    // Create a temporary MutableDictionary to store the items fields in, which will eventually end up in blogEntries
    NSMutableDictionary *blogItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    // Create a counter variable as type "int"
    int counter;
    
    // Loop through the children of the current  node
    for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {
        // Add each field to the blogItem Dictionary with the node name as key and node value as the value
        [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];
                    NSLog(@"Data = %@",[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue]);
        
    }
    
    // Add the blogItem to the global blogEntries Array so that the view can access it.
    [blogEntries addObject:[blogItem copy]];
    
}
        [YourTable reloadData];
```

}

Import touchXML library in you header file.

Thanks

Comment: hi thanks for reply, users will provide search strings like CNN or BBC and the app needs to search internet to get rss xml urls. your code is asking for URL? how to do it with just a string like CNN or BBC.?